# C# Use an immutable collection or reduce the accessibility of the field(s) 'CreateContactMapping'

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sonarqube, immutability

**I'm having a problem with a class in an old project and I don't know how to refactor this part, I get the following error message from sonarcube:**

```
Use an immutable collection or reduce the accessibility of the field(s) 'CreateContactMapping'.Why is this an issue?
```

This is the piece of code

```cs
public static readonly Dictionary<string, Func<UpdateContactServiceRequest, object>> UpdateContactMapping =
    new Dictionary<string, Func<UpdateContactServiceRequest, object>>
    {
        { "firstname", req => req.FirstName },
        { "lastname", req => req.LastName },
        { "full_name", req => req.FullName },
        { "email", req => req.Email },
        { "phone", req => req.Phone },
        { "date_of_birth", req => req.BirthDate },
        { "job_title", req => req.JobTitle },
        { "occupation", req => req.Occupation },
        { "renda", req => req.MonthlyIncome },
        { "lifecyclestage", req => req.LifeCycleStage },
        { "hs_lead_status", req => req.LeadStatus },
        { "ali_email_validated", req => req.EmailValidated },
        { "ali_sms_token_validated", req => req.CellphoneValidated },
        { "id_da_proposta_atual", req => req.CurrentProposalId },
        { "contact_type", req => req.ContactType }
    };
```

How best to solve this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

One solution could be to change `Dictionary` to `ImmutableDictionary`, then run `.ToImmutableDictionary()` after initializing the dictionary.

```cs
public static readonly ImmutableDictionary<string, Func<UpdateContactServiceRequest, object>> UpdateContactMapping =
    new Dictionary<string, Func<UpdateContactServiceRequest, object>>
    {
        { "firstname", req => req.FirstName },
        { "lastname", req => req.LastName },
        { "full_name", req => req.FullName },
        { "email", req => req.Email },
        { "phone", req => req.Phone },
        { "date_of_birth", req => req.BirthDate },
        { "job_title", req => req.JobTitle },
        { "occupation", req => req.Occupation },
        { "renda", req => req.MonthlyIncome },
        { "lifecyclestage", req => req.LifeCycleStage },
        { "hs_lead_status", req => req.LeadStatus },
        { "ali_email_validated", req => req.EmailValidated },
        { "ali_sms_token_validated", req => req.CellphoneValidated },
        { "id_da_proposta_atual", req => req.CurrentProposalId },
        { "contact_type", req => req.ContactType }
    }.ToImmutableDictionary();
```

Comment: That solved my problem, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Use an immutable collection: Instead of a Dictionary<string, Func<UpdateContactServiceRequest, object>>, you can use an immutable collection such as ImmutableDictionary<string, Func<UpdateContactServiceRequest, object>>. This ensures that the contents of the collection cannot be modified after initialization. Here's an example:

```
public static readonly ImmutableDictionary<string, Func<UpdateContactServiceRequest, object>> UpdateContactMapping = ImmutableDictionary<string, Func<UpdateContactServiceRequest, object>>.Empty
    .Add("firstname", req => req.FirstName)
    .Add("lastname", req => req.LastName)
    .Add("full_name", req => req.FullName)
    // Add the rest of the key-value pairs
    ;
```

Reduce accessibility: If you want to keep using Dictionary<string, Func<UpdateContactServiceRequest, object>>, you can reduce the accessibility of the field to restrict direct modification from external code. For example, you can change the accessibility to private or internal depending on your requirements. Then, you can provide a public method or property to access the contents of the dictionary in a controlled manner.

```
private static readonly Dictionary<string, Func<UpdateContactServiceRequest, object>> UpdateContactMapping = new Dictionary<string, Func<UpdateContactServiceRequest, object>>
{
    { "firstname", req => req.FirstName },
    { "lastname", req => req.LastName },
    // Add the rest of the key-value pairs
};

public static IReadOnlyDictionary<string, Func<UpdateContactServiceRequest, object>> GetUpdateContactMapping()
{
    return UpdateContactMapping;
}
```